# Python package is installed but can't be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im not running in a virtual environment but when I want to import the py module robobrowser it gives me the error "No module named 'robobrowser"

Even though when I install it via pip or pip3 it tells me the requirements are already satisfied

Comment: That depends on where you installed it.

Comment: I just noticed that the package is also not in my pip list, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: @chepner just a regular pip install so it should be in the folder where all packages get installed

Comment: Use `pip -V` command to check where your modules are being installed.

Comment: not just pip -V but specifically ensure the version of python that pip installed it for and the version of python you are trying to import are the same.

Comment: This is where it tells me the module is installed
c:\users\QuantKan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages